# PHP Free memory through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, memory, pdo

I was wondering if there's any method from the mysqli class for free memory after a `get_result()`, I saw that people uses `closeCursor()` method, but compiler says:

```
Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::closeCursor()
```

and I call it through my prepared statement object like this `$Statement->closeCursor();`

I saw that closeCursor method closes the connection to the database too, so does it means that if I want to make another query I need to re-instantiate the mysqli class again? if so then, is there any other way I can do the same but leaving an opened connection? I'm only interested in free all the variables that result_sets leaves and start another query normally, thank's!

By the way, I'm doing this for a custom mysql backup system I'm just making, cheers! - Edgar.

Comment: PDO doesn't have anything to do with MySQLi.  Which are you using?

Comment: Before nothing thank's for answering, I'm sorry, I am using MySQLi, (I always though PDO = Prepared Object), firstable I create a mysqli instance and then I use the stmt_init method for create the statement object.

Comment: Well, I was figuring if I could just free the results of the queries without affect the class itself lol, but it looks like I will have to unset the object or assign it to null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closeCursor()` is not a mysqli statement method.

What you are looking for is [free_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.free-result.php) and [free](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)

Comment: Good one I didn't saw that @Neo is calling closeCursor in wrong way , it should be like this PDOStatement :: closeCursor() . instead he has posted as mysqli static method .

Comment: All I just needed, next time I have to read the manual very well before ask lol, by the way thank's to everyone for answering!

Comment: There is nothing wrong @Neo , It really helps other SO visitors

Answer (score 1):

I could find an alternative to closeCursor ,using which you can free results , with out closing connection . ( this snippet is posted at manual in the comment section )

```
<?php 
/** 
 * @param PDOStatement $oStm 
 */ 
public static function closeCursor($oStm) { 
    do $oStm->fetchAll(); 
    while ($oStm->nextRowSet()); 
} 
?>
```

from PHP manual [PDOStatement::closeCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php)

As per the manual there

PDOStatement::closeCursor() is implemented either as an optional driver specific method (allowing for maximum efficiency), or as the generic PDO fallback if no driver specific function is installed. The PDO generic fallback is semantically the same as writing the following code in your PHP script:

```
<?php
do {
    while ($stmt->fetch())
        ;
    if (!$stmt->nextRowset())
        break;
} while (true);
?>
```

Hope this helps